# How to list vertices coordinates from selected edge

Tags: vertices

I need to list the **extremities of an edge**. I've got a **selected edge** in edit mode and I need to **list the coordinates**. This will be very useful!

This because I'm looking for the rotation of an edge on the XY plane. I've already figured out how to get the angle but I need the two vertices coordinates to start the math.
Hope there is a built-in method!

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will display the  coordinates of the selected vertices of the selected object  ( you have the local and the world coordinates as @poor have noted )

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
#all selected vertices indecies
verts_ind = [i.index for i in obj.data.vertices if i.select]
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')

for i in verts_ind :
    local_co = obj.data.vertices[i].co
    world_co = obj.matrix_world * local_co
    print(world_co)
```

Comment: You are too fast :) What about `obj.matrix_world * obj.data.vertices[i].co`?

Comment: Thank you both for the world coordinates. The `local_co` will also be useful.

Comment: with blender 2.8 need to replace * by @
world_co = obj.matrix_world @ local_co

Answer (score 0):

Bmesh module variant, which does not require a mode change:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

mat = ob.matrix_world

for edge in bm.edges:
    if edge.select:
        print("Edge {}\n".format(edge.index))
        for vert in edge.verts:
            print("  Vertex {}:".format(vert.index))
            print("    ", vert.co, "local")
            print("    ", mat * vert.co, "global\n")
        break
```

Note that above code works in edit-mode only, but it's also possible to extend it with support for object mode.